# Не дать повторно запустится setInterval()

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть функция, примерно такая:

```
function fun() {
    setInterval(function() {...}, 1000);
}
```

Эта функция вызывается при клике на элемент из списка и с промежутком в одну секунду изменяет текст в другом элементе.
При клике на другой элемент запускается вторая такая же функция и уже они обе изменяют значение в элементе.
Собственно как можно завершит выполнение одного setInterval и запустить другой?
PS: clearInterval пытался использовать, но или я рукожоп или не канает.

Comment: А как вы пробовали использовать `clearInterval` ?

Comment: Сам на себя уже ответил.

Answer (score 1):

Да, оказалось я не правильно использовал clearInterval():

```
var val;

function fun() {
    clearInterval(val);
    val = setInterval(function() {...}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

При установке интервала вам надо получить его идентификатор. Для отмены надо вызвать clearInterval передав ей идентификатор интервала.

для установки интервала:

```
var id = setInterval(alert('tick'), 1000);
```

для отмены интервала

```
clearInterval(id);
```